How to select only deformation bones?
Is there a way to select all bones from the vertex group of the mesh?
I have too many overlapping bones that are very tedious to work and some are non-deformer which I wanted to hide and only work with the ones that are applied under the vertex group for weight Paint.  I can always do this by hand but it'll be extremely time-consuming to go everyone.

@Xana  I'm sorry, I know nothing about scripting.  "BPY is not defined"   I don't even know what it means.   It also give me file destination error  with    How to set it up and if it's as simple as copying the line or do I have to reference the name. I need examples
